# C++ VS2010 compiling options

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compilation

Could you, please, advice me which options i should use when compiling with VS2010 to optimise assembly, detele function names and maybe other options for anti-reverse engineering?

Thanks!

Comment: Maximum optimization makes it quite hard to follow the assembly code. Debug symbols are stored in a separate file (.pdb), so just don't distribute that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this Anti-Reverse Engineering Guide: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30815/An-Anti-Reverse-Engineering-Guide By Josh_Jackson (Prize winner in Competition "Best C++/MFC article of November 2008").

- ProcessDebugFlags
- Debug Object Handle
- Thread Hiding
- BlockInput
  and so long ...

Old but good!

HTH